# Unity rigidbody2d velocity converges to 0 over time for 1 axis at random

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a very simple program where it creates edgecolliders on the edges of the screen, and then launches an ellipse that has a circleCollider2d attached to it with impulse force.

I set all the colliders (edge and circle) to use the bouncy material with bounciness set at 1.0 (infinite bounce).

I am having a strange issue where over time, one of the axis of velocity converges to 0. For example

```
this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (new Vector2 (100, 100), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

What happens is that the object will start moving in a diagonal fashion, but given enough bounces, the velocity goes to just alternating between (100,0) and (-100,0). This can happen either where the x axis goes to 0 or the Y axis goes to 0. It depends on which one was higher during the start.

I am not sure why this is happening. Basically visually, the object will start bouncing around, and after about 10 bounces or so, it will just be bouncing back and forth in a straight line instead of preserving the other axis as well. I have no idea why it does that. I don't have any of the constraints on (I also tried constraining Z axis rotation, but that did nothing).

bouncyness on all edge colliders as well as the circle collider are set to 1.0.
The rigid body has mass at 1, and all drag coefficients are set to 0 as well.
The intention is for it to just bounce endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question here as I just realized why this is happening once I observed the behavior of the rotation. It completely did not occur to me that friction would have a hand in this, especially since friction in this case was resulting in the same simulation each time.

Along with turning bounciness to a 1, you must also turn friction to 0.